# How to pass variables from view to controller without using forms in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, view, controller

I'm using RESTful controller and passing variables (using forms) works just fine here.

Now for some reason I need to use simple link, created with `action()` and dedicated route for `@create` action.

My view creates few similar links with different parameters:

```
<a href="{!! action('\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Franch\Category\SubCategoryController@create', array('mainCategoryName' => $mainCategoryName)) !!}">
```

It works, because I can see this in URL:

`/create?mainCategoryName=some_sample_name`

But the route doesn't pass variables to the @create action OR controller doesn't recieve it for somereason:

```
Route::get('admin/franch/sub_categories/create', ['uses' => 'Admin\Franch\Category\SubCategoryController@create');
```

I wonder how can I pass variables from views to specific controllers, using GET and POST methods?

And this is my @create controller:

```
public function create($mainCategoryName = false)
{
        dd($mainCategoryName);
....
```

Which is always gives `false`.

Comment: The parameter is passed as a query string so if you want to access it in the create function you can do public function create(Request $request){ dd($request->get('mainCategoryName'));

Comment: $mainCategoryName should be string to be able to get converted to URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well You can create a function on the link and in that function user Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",//Or Get
  url: url,
  data: {"var_name":variable},
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Now you can send you variables in the data. and then you can get value of the variable in your controller  by:

```
Input::get('var_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better if you make all your "calculations" in the controller and pass a resulting value to the view like so

```
class SomeController() extends Controller
{
    public function getView():View
    {
        $mainCategoryName = "fix";
        $formUrl = action('\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Franch\Category\SubCategoryController@create', array('mainCategoryName' => $mainCategoryName));

        return view('view.show', compact('formUrl'));
    }
...
```

Your mistake is in keeping meaningful data in the view, when the view should only have processed values:

```
<a href="{!! $formUrl !!}">
```

And if you really want to go "nuts", you can create a class that would generate HTML using a blade-view and the controller data and then you can execute this class in the controller to have your "partial" ready to be incorporated in a view as HTML. But not the other way round. Keep the calculations out of your views.